# Why do I get The property is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified when i did not touch it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

here is the relevant piece of code :

```
var pageToEdit = _context.WikiPages.Find(i_PageToCreate.PageID);
pageRevisionToAdd = new WikiPageRevision();
pageRevisionToAdd.Content = i_PageToCreate.Content;
pageRevisionToAdd.CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
pageRevisionToAdd.ParentWikiPageID = pageToEdit.ID;
pageRevisionToAdd.CreatorID = -1;

foreach (var rev in pageToEdit.Revisions)
{
     rev.RevisionState = WikiPageRevision.eRevisionState.History;
}
pageRevisionToAdd.RevisionState = WikiPageRevision.eRevisionState.Baseline;
pageToEdit.Revisions.Add(pageRevisionToAdd);
    
_context.SaveChanges();
```

and when it gets to `_context.SaveChanges();` i get the error:

> The property 'RevisionID' is part of the object's key information and
> cannot be modified.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The property
> 'RevisionID' is part of the object's key information and cannot be
> modified.

I did not touch the revision ID.. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Is there some code in `RevisionState` property which modifies revision id?

Comment: $%@$%@$ you were right it was an enum property that updated the RevisionID instead of the RevisionStateID

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug...
It was a property defined to encapsulate the RvisionStateID using an enum.

```
    public eRevisionState RevisionState 
    {
        get { return (eRevisionState)RevisionID; } // ..should be RevisionStateID
        set { RevisionID = (int)value; } // ..should be RevisionStateID
    }
```

Comment: Good, now you can close the question :)